# bash one-line conditional fails when using set -e

Tags: bash

I started using set -e in my bash scripts,
and discovered that short form of conditional expression breaks the script execution.

For example the following line should check that $var is not empty:

```
[ -z "$var" ] && die "result is empty"
```

But causes silent exit from script when $var has non-zero length.

I used this form of conditional expression in many places...

What should I do to make it run correctly? Rewrite everything with "if" construction (which would be ugly)? Or abandon "set -e"?

**Edit: Everybody is asking for the code. Here is full [non]working example:**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

function check_me()
{
    ws="smth"
    [ -z "$ws" ] && echo " fail" && exit 1
}

echo "checking wrong thing"
check_me
echo "check finished"
```

I'd expect it to print both echoes before and after function call.
But it silently fails in the check_me function. Output is:

```
checking wrong thing
```

Comment: Where did you use `set -e`? show the full code.

Comment: What you describe should not happen (and I can't repro). This is specifically listed as a case where the shell does not exit in the man page.

Comment: It might be the usage which makes sense here. i've added a sample script(complete).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
[ -n "$var" ] || die "result is empty"
```

This way, the return value of the entire statement is true if `$var` is non-empty, so the `ERR` trap is not triggered.

Comment: @LiMar: do you expect a function called `die` to ever return?

Comment: @ams: No I do not. It's just a wrapper around "echo" followed by "exit 1"

Comment: @LiMar: so, if the test returns false, it will call die, and everything will work as expected. If the tests returns true, then the script will continue. I don't see your problem here?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you will have to rewrite everything so no false statements occur.

The definition of `set -e` is clear:

> -e      Exit  immediately if a simple command (see SHELL GRAMMAR above) exits with a non-zero status.  The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part of the test in an if statement, part of a && or || list, or if the command's return value is being inverted via !.  A trap on ERR, if set, is  executed before the shell exits.

You are using the "optimization" system of Bash: because a false statement will cause an AND (`&&`) statement never to be true, bash knows it doesn't have to execute the second part of the line.  However, this is a clever "abuse" of the system, not intended behaviour and therefore incompatible with `set -e`.  You will have to rewrite everything so it is using proper `if`s.

Answer (score 2):

You should write your script such that no command ever exits with non-zero status.

In your command `[ -z "$var" ]` can be true, in which case you call `die`, or false in which case `-e` does it's thing.

Either write it with `if`, as you say, or use something like this:

```
[ -z "$var" ] && die "result is empty" || true
```

I'd recommend `if` though.

Comment: As @I0b0 says, there's a prettier way for this specific example, but the above will work for anything.

Comment: [Be very wary of that approach](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3). In this case it might work, but it's tricky to know what the effect will be if the commands are non-trivial.

Answer (score 1):

What the bash help isn't very clear on is that only the *last* statement in an `&&` or `||` chain is subject to causing an exit under `set -e`.  `foo && bar` will exit if `bar` returns false, but not if `foo` returns false.

So your script should work...  but it doesn't.  Why?

It's not because of the failed `-z` test.  It's because that failure makes the **function** *return a non-zero status*:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

function check_me()
{
    ws="smth"
    [ -z "$ws" ] && echo " fail" && exit 1
    # The line above fails, setting $? to 1
    # The function now returns, returning 1!
}

echo "checking wrong thing"
check_me   # function returns 1, causing exit here
echo "check finished"
```

So there are multiple ways to fix this.  You could add `||true` to the conditional inside the function, or to the line that calls `check_me`.  But as others have pointed out, using `||true` has its own problems.

In this specific scenario, where the desired postcondition of `check_me` is "either this thing is valid or the script has exited", the straightforward thing to do is to write it like that, i.e.  `[[ -n "$ws" ]] || die "whatever"`.

But using `&&` conditions will actually work fine with `set -e` in general, as long as you don't use such a conditional *as the last thing in a function*.  You need to add an explicit `true` or `return 0` or even `:` as a statement following such a conditional, unless you *intend* the function to return false when the condition fails.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, the others are incomplete when it comes to that point.
I generally just end all functions with either `return 0` or `return $?` to prevent the issue an keep them maintainable.